# How to call a php helper function from a form in, a joomla module?

Tags: php, module, joomla4

Pardon me first for ***being a beginner in php and in joomla development*** (hello @mickmackusa!).
I am creating a module which uses a form to first load users then on submit would display order items ordered by a client selected from the form.
I have both parts of the question almost solved, that is, the list of users being displayed and data retrieved from the database if I select one user but I can do this separately.
My question is: in my helper file, I have 2 functions for retrieving users (getUsers) and for retrieving client data (getDetails). The only issue I have is: how to set the form's action to call my getDetails function in my module's template file?
I have tried

`<form id="myform" method="post" action="getDetails()">` which does not work.

I have also tried

`<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo getDetails();?>">`

which does not work either as I get a 404 error.

I guess I'm missing a basic thing here but could not find any answer.

Thanks to help me to get this to work.